# Regex, get prices. But dots or commas for decimals

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the prices out of text using regex.

Small example:
"This great product only for €1.000,59 today!"

I would like to get the price from the text as written above. This is my python regex so far:

```
re.findall(ur'([0-9,.]*)', text)
```

There is only a small problem. Some texts use commas (,) for splitting the decimals, others use dots (.) and some of them don't even have decimals or replaced the 00 decimals with a dash (-), like €59,-

So the ideal situation, to get all prices without any problem would be (in my opinion):

- If you check the numbers from right to left, is the 3rd character a dot or comma (cause every price does not contain more than 2 decimals)?
- Does it contain a dash (like €50,-)?

If both is NO:  remove all dots and commas.
If one of the two questions is YES: if the decimals are seperated by a dot (.), replace that dot with a comma, or if it's already a comma, just leave it like that. And remove the rest of the commas and dots.

Is that possible with regex?

Comment: a single ex wouldn't be enough. Provide more along with the expected output.

Comment: How about looking for a currency symbol? Also, have you tried googling for "regex" and "currency"?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, could you maybe help with a solution which might work? With a extra split function or something? Does not matter really in which language. I can translate it :P

Comment: @tobias_k 
The problem is not really splitting the price from the text. The main problem are the dots and commas. We save it as decimal in the database. If it doesn't contain any decimals, postgres will add them. But if it does contain decimals, we would like to extract them. But you can read the problem in my first post.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen try this `\.(?=\d{2}\b)`, then replace the matched `.` with `,`

Comment: Is `1,000` a valid price (a price without decimals)

Comment: (\d+)?[,\.]?(\d+)?[,\.]?(\d+)[,\.-]+(\d+)? and replace with \1\2\3,\4 This will return a blank for a - but that should not matter I think. i.e "59,-" turns into "59,". (you could alternatively add 00 to the end of the replace string) And it is limited to a billion but it is not likely you come across a space shuttle for sale I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Sorry, I did not read the problem description carefully enough. I think to solve the problem, you need two regex patterns. First do a `re.sub()` then `re.findall()`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(([.,]{1})(\d{1,3}|-))')  
s = "2,456,777.00  xxxxxxxxxxxxx 59,789,- xxxxxxxxxxxx 59,-  xxxxxxxxxx 1.000,59"

def subs(m):
    g0 = m.group(0)
    g3 = m.group(3)

    if g3 == '-':
        g3 = '00'
    if len(g0) == 4:
        return ',' + g0[1:4]
    else:
        return '.' + g3

c = re.findall(r'[\d.,-]+', re.sub(pattern, subs, s))
print c

>> ['2,456,777.00', '59,789.00', '59.00', '1,000.59']
```

A little cumbersome indeed. Hope someone can come up with a smarter one.

Comment: I have to say, works very nice so far. Guess I have to add the functionality for replacing the decimal separators, dashes etc. by using some other functions ?:)

Comment: Replace the decimal separators? Could you make it a little more clear?

Comment: That's the main issue so far. We have to deliver the right decimal format to postgres (2456777 OR 2456777.00). ```([0-9,.]*)``` worked fine to get the whole price in the first case, but because we replaced the commas with dots (1.000,59 became 1.000.59), postgres actually saved 1.00. See my "ideal" situation in my first post.

Comment: And here in holland we have sites with prices like 1.000,59, 1,000.59, 1.000,-, 1,000 and 1.000. So that's what I tried to explain in my first post. The best way to check the string contains decimals or not, is to check or the 3rd character from the right is a dot or comma. Well the rest is explained in my first post.

Comment: You should add an explanation for what your regexp does exactly.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen The last separator can be extracted by a group like `((\d{1,3}([,\.]{1}))*[\d|-]{1,})`. This is not hard. But it seems that you want to ensure all thousand separators are commas, decimal separator is dot?